# What word describes text having a different meaning backwards and forwards?

Tags: antonyms, semantics, terminology, taxonomy, palindrome

Jonathan Reed's poem 'Lost Generation' is a pessimistic view of the future if read forwards. However, if you read it backwards linewise (not wordwise), it is still semantically meaningful, but the meaning is optimistic and almost completely opposite.

Here are a few lines backwards and forwards to demonstrate:

> In the future
> Environmental destruction will be the norm
> No longer can it be said that
> My peers and I care about this earth
> It will be evident that
> My generation is apathetic and lethargic
> It is foolish to presume that
> There is hope

vs

> There is hope
> It is foolish to presume that
> My generation is apathetic and lethargic
> It will be evident that
> My peers and I care about this earth
> No longer can it be said that
> Environmental destruction will be the norm
> In the future

Of course, the first word that comes to mind is palindromic. However, a palindrome is exactly the same forwards and backwards (discounting punctuation) whereas this is opposite forward and backwards - so pretty much the antonym of a palindrome.

I've spent a while searching for an existing word to describe this to no avail, so I am deferring to the geniuses here :-)

Comment: "Poem".  All of them have a different meaning read backwards. Usually it is a nonsensical one, though.

Comment: That could be said about any text though. Your comment backwards reads 'Though, one nonsensical a is it usually. Backwards read meaning different a have them of all. "Poem"'. It also has a different meaning read backwards (wordwise in this case, as your comment was only one line) albeit nonsensical, yet it is not a poem.

I was asking about the specific literary device used in the example above. If there isn't currently a term for it, I would like to know that too.

Comment: We don't always have names for things that are isolated incidents without overall use.  The story with no letter E in it is just a story.  It's quirk is just a quirk and not essential.  My arm has a freckle on the wrist.  There is no accepted name for this kind of arm.

Comment: True, but the specific example you gave - the story with no letter E - does have a name: it is a lipogram. So we do give names even to isolated incidents. I am, however, willing to accept that, like your wristfreckledarm, there is currently no word in common use for this case.

Comment: *read backwards it means the opposite* is the best descriptor so far. This is a great example; thanks for your question. Hopefully a poet will be able to answer your question. I'll ask one today. (honest)

Comment: @Susan - Thanks, I appreciate that! It's just that knowing about lipograms (see comment above) and Pilish (writing text whose word lengths correspond to the appropriate digit of pi) got me thinking that if obscure things like these have names, then surely this would.

Comment: I just emailed this to a professor of poetry at a nearby university. I'm sure she'll have something to say. It might take a day or two for her to get back. Do check in from time to time! :)

Comment: Thanks, I will do! This is my first time on the site, but I believe I've got email notifications set up correctly, so I'll be back :)

Comment: @MattDuffin, thanks for  the word "lipogram" which is a new one to me. Lipograms would seem to come within the realm of OuLiPo, which is "An acronym for Ouvroir de Littérature Potentielle (Workshop for Potential Literature), a group of writers and mathematicians formed in France in 1960... OuLiPo rejects spontaneous chance and the subconscious as sources of literary creativity. Instead, the group emphasizes systematic, self-restricting means of making texts." https://www.poetryfoundation.org/learn/glossary-terms/oulipo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is called a **reverse poem**.  It differs from a palindrome, as a palindrome is only about the reversal of the words/lines and it doesn't involve semantics.

> The double-back nature of reverse poems plays tricks on their audience. These poems mean one thing when read from top to bottom, but the meaning or sentiment changes when you read each line from bottom to top. 
> *[penandthepad.com](https://penandthepad.com/write-reverse-poem-8556361.html)*

---

The excerpt in my original answer:

> Reverse poems make sense when read frontwards and backwards. There are three main types of reverse poems: those that reverse line by line, those that reverse word by word, and those that simply reverse the message without the above wordplay. 
> [*ehow.com*](http://www.ehow.com/how_8556361_write-reverse-poem.html)

Comment: Thanks @ermanen. This does seem to be an accurate description of the original example. It's just surprising (and embarrassing) that after considering antigram, anadrome, semordnilap and crab canon that something as prosaic as 'reverse poem' seems to be the right answer. Still, nothing wrong with calling a spade a spade.

Answer (score 5):

You might consider the term *crab canon*.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crab_canon):

> A crab canon — also known by the Latin form of the name, *canon cancrizans* — is an arrangement of two musical lines that are complementary and backward, similar to a palindrome.

Yes, that's more of a musical term than a literary term, but the Wikipedia article goes on to say:

> The use of the term in non-musical contexts was popularized by Douglas Hofstadter in *Gödel, Escher, Bach*.

Hofstadter's brilliant Crab Canon from *GEB* can be found on [this page](http://www.evl.uic.edu/swami/crabcanon).

---

<sup>What's the difference between a musical crab canon and a literary one? Well, to be precise, one has no frets.</sup>

Comment: I really like this! I have to say that I prefer the Latin term because 'crab canon' doesn't sound very pleasing to me :-) ... I may be missing something, but what's the etymology? Where does 'crab' come from?

Comment: Ah, I have just pictured a musical score with a crab walking along it sideways - backwards and forwards. I guess I was thinking too much of a literary use of 'crab canon' where this image wouldn't work so well.

Comment: @MattDuffin - Yes, I think that's it. If you've observed how crabs walk, it should make sense. Many crabs walk from backwards (or from side-to-side) with as much grace and agility as forwards – like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ll2tq_MbnKQ).

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, this type of prose is indeed called a **palindrome poem**, or otherwise known as **mirrored poetry**.

A palindrome, by definition, is a word, phrase, verse, sentence, or even poem that reads the same forward or backward. It stems from the Greek word *palindromos*: *palin*, meaning again, and *dromos*, meaning a running.

The rules for writing a similar poem are the following.

> 1. You must use the same words in the first half of the poem as the second half, but
> 2. Reverse the order for the second half, and
> 3. Use a word in the middle as a bridge from the first half to the second half of the poem

A further example of a palindrome poem

**[Good and Evil](http://www.writing.com/main/books/entry_id/725758)**
Mirrored
are we,
images like ourselves
reflecting, perfect and opposite,
good and evil
- within -
evil and good,
opposite and perfect, reflecting
ourselves like images,
we are
mirrored.

---

Sources from [here](http://www.shadowpoetry.com/resources/wip/palindrome.html) and [here](http://www.writersdigest.com/editor-blogs/poetic-asides/personal-updates/poetic-form-palindrome-poetry-or-mirror-poem)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, I already considered whether it was a palindrome and decided it was not (although I am happy to accept I am wrong). Namely, this is because of the strict requirement for a palindrome to be the *exact same* (except punctuation) forwards and backwards. Additionally, this poem does not meet the rules specified. Perhaps I made it seem as though it does by setting out an example and its opposite below it - this was my formatting and not in the original, so sorry if this caused confusion. The original has only the 'forward' text.

Comment: Just seen your updated answer - the Good and Evil poem uses the exact same words in the opposite order, whereas Lost Generation keeps the word order within a each line, but reverses the line order. This difference is making me lean more against palindrome.

Comment: Another great example! This, however, truly is a palindrome (of words, not letters), whereas the OP's poem is not.

Comment: @MattDuffin That's fine, I Googled for a bit and found these references and finally a palindrome poem that I actually liked! I think your question is a very good one.

Answer (score 3):

The word you want is antigram.

Edited to add [source](http://www.goodworksonearth.org/antigrams-smargixel-semordnilap-trianagrams.html).

Comment: Thanks @fdb. Your 'antigram' idea got me looking in a different direction. I didn't like 'antigram' because one can rearrange the letters in any order to create the antigram. However, I did come across 'anadrome' and 'semordnilap', which require a strict reversal of letter order. Despite these being the closest we have come so far, they all rely on the reversal of letter order, rather than line order. I will keep searching along the road inspired by your post :)

Comment: Good try, but OP's poem does not meet the definition.

Comment: An antigram is something that can be read forwards or backwards with opposite meanings. There are two types: You can reverse the words or the letters.

Comment: @fdb thanks for the clarification. I think that 'anadrome' and 'semordnilap' are closer because they require a strict reversal of the order whereas 'antigram' is an anagram of the word, which forms its antonym. However, none of these words (anadrome, semordnilap or antigram) operate on a line-by-line level - rather letter-by-letter or word-by-word.

Comment: @fdb, however, I wouldn't have come across those terms if it weren't for your post, so thanks for putting me on that track.

Comment: @MattDuffin - I was about to post the same. I feel that anadrome is the closest and most euphonic, but as you say - nothing seems to work on a line basis.

Comment: @Epicentre agreed, it is a mellifluous word. I do like the wryness of semordnilap though, which is itself a semordnilap (although purposely and trivially constructed to be so).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know an official word, but would throw out *invertible*.

The word means capable of inversion, which this poem clearly is.  You are inverting the order of its lines and the result is a new poem.

Inverting a function in mathematics means turning it upside down and typically resulting in a new value for the resulting function.  This is essentially the same.

Granted this word **ONLY** functions if you are not looking for the meaning to be completely opposite, only meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

A general term for hiding a different message inside a text that seems to mean something else is a **code**, **cryptogram** or **steganography**.